# Why is the output of \pageref{label} not a string?

Tags: page-numbering, strings

I made a small macro to create crossreferences from one footnote to another. The page number of the referenced footnote should not be printed if both footnotes appear on the same page. That should be pretty straightforward, or so I thought:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\footnotecrossref}[2]{%
  #1 footnote~\ref{#2}\comparepn{\pageref{#2}}{\thepage}%
}

% String version
%~ \newcommand{\comparepn}[2]{%
  %~ \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}
    %~ {}
    %~ { on page~#1}%
%~ }

%Numeric version
\newcommand{\comparepn}[2]{%
  \ifthenelse{#1=#2}
    {}
    { on page~#1}%
}


\begin{document}
%~ \pagenumbering{roman}
This is some text.\footnote{\label{fn:test}This is a clever footnote.}

%~ \newpage

This is more text.\footnote{\footnotecrossref{See}{fn:test}}
\end{document}
```

This works as expected. until we uncomment the line `\pagenumbering{roman}` -- then we'll get a "Missing number" error, which is reasonable as roman numbers are letters and no normal numbers. So, if we really don't care about the numeric value, it should be better to use string comparison. But if I uncomment the block under "String version" and comment out the block under "Numeric version", it still won't work! I get no LaTeX error, but the page number is printed. Apparently, the two arguments are different although both footnotes are on the same page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trailing `\null` in output of `\pageref{fn:test}`, so to compare by string, `\comparepn{\pageref{#2}}{\thepage\null}` would work. (Note this workaround is *very fragile*.)

Related definitions:

```
% latex.ltx, line 5553:
\def\pageref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
                                   \@secondoftwo{#1}}

% latex.ltx, line 5543:
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null % <<< the \null is inserted here
  \fi}
```

Alternatively, there are expandable variants of `\pageref` provided by packages which do not contain the trailing `\null`. For example, `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` package and `\crtcrefpage` from `crossreftools` package. But then you might need to handle category code differences.

Here is a `\getpagerefnumber` attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\footnotecrossref}[2]{%
  #1 footnote~\ref{#2}%
  \comparepn
    {\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}}}
    {\thepage}%
}

\newcommand{\comparepn}[2]{%
  % compare by stings
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}
    {}
    { on page~#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
This is some text.\footnote{\label{fn:test}This is a clever footnote.}

%~ \newpage

This is more text.\footnote{\footnotecrossref{See}{fn:test}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. I didn't get `\comparepn{\pageref{#2}}{\thepage\null}` to work, so I put that off for a while and dealt with improving the document contents first. As I use `cleveref`, I adapted  your example for `crossreftools`, and this works as expected. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Andreas I've added a note to warning readers that "adding `\null`" is fragile.